# Shift column in excel while creating excel in java using org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

how to shift the column in excel while creating excel in java using org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("abc");
  Row sheetRow = sheet.createRow((short)0);
List headers=values fetched from db
  Cell headerCell = null;
  for(int k=0;k<headers.size();k++){
   headerCell = sheetRow.createCell(k);
  if(somecondition){
headerCell.setCellValue(rt);
}else{
  sheetRow.removecell(headerCell);
}
 }
```

.removecell is removing content but i want to delete the column,i.e shift the column to left.

Comment: What about not creating the column, I mean you're crafting the excel sheet, so..

Comment: I believe with `POI`, you can specify the row/col you want to save text to. See here: http://hmkcode.com/apache-poi-java-read-write-excel/.

Comment: Why do you create a cell an `if not condition` delete it again? Try filtering out those values first, or move the `sheetRow.createCell(k);` code into the `if(somecondition){ ...}` block. Why do you fetch values from a DB if you don't plan to use it? Can't you specify your Condition as a SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

try using this code

```
    sheet.shiftRows(3, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
```

In this code snippet, 3 is indicate row shift to 3rd index means 4th row , sheet.getLastRowNum() is indicate last row index and 1 indicate how many row is shifted.

Comment: This will shift all rows. Not just that column.